# I have a PL/SQL. How to use the returned value of a procedure as another parameter to search other information?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, cursor

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE PAID_REPORT 
(
  PAYMENT_STATUS IN VARCHAR2  
) AS

linecount number(4);
linecounttwo number(4);
--animal varchar2 (12);
animaltype varchar2(12);
visitid number (6);

cursor vetCursor is 
select pb_vet.vetid,visitid,lastname,firstname
from pb_visit,pb_vet
where pb_visit.vetid = pb_vet.vetid
and pb_visit.status = PAYMENT_STATUS
order by lastname, firstname;
vetRow vetCursor%rowtype;

cursor visitCursor is
select visitid,name,lastname,firstname
from pb_client,pb_animal,pb_visit
where pb_client.cliEntid=pb_animal.clientid
and pb_visit.animalid=pb_animal.animalid
and status = PAYMENT_STATUS;
visitRow visitCursor%rowtype;

BEGIN
linecounttwo:=0;
open visitCursor;
loop
fetch visitCursor
into visitRow;
exit when visitCursor%notfound;
linecounttwo:=linecounttwo+1;

end loop;


  linecount:=0;
  open vetCursor;
  loop
  fetch vetCursor
  into vetRow;

  exit when vetCursor%notfound;
  dbms_output.put_line('Veterinarian ID: '||vetRow.vetid||'   '||vetRow.lastname||','||vetRow.firstname);  

   linecount:=linecount+1;
  end loop;
  close vetCursor;
END PAID_REPORT;
```

it will print out a couple of lines of VETID Info
    what I want to do is that under each vetID, I want to use this vetID in another select sentence to search somthing else like select ...from...where id=vetID

now I have got two lines of vetID displayed as I expected, but I dont know how to use it.
I dont know if I have made myself clear because English is not my first languange. so I will use a easy example to show what I want to do.

CLASS ID:  0001          English

```
     Student A    19
     Student B    21
```

CLASS ID:  0004          Maths

```
     Student A    19
     Student B    21
```

its like I have got the lines of CLASS ID, then for each CLASS ID I want to use it as
select name, age
from Student
where........
and ID = CLASSID;
the thing is I dont know what the CLASS ID is..

thank you. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show what your other select statement is.  You can create another loop.   Is there any reason why you can't use one sql query to join the tables?  Please show your table schemas and what you are expecting as output.

Comment: thx for reply. my other statement would be something like select ...from...where id = THE_RETURNED_VETID; actually I tried to use a single query.
select pb_vet.vetid,visitid,pb_client.lastname as cLast,pb_client.firstname as cFirst,pb_vet.firstname as vFirst,pb_vet.lastname as vLast,pb_animaltype.name as tName
,pb_animal.name as aName
from pb_visit,pb_vet,pb_animal,pb_client,pb_animaltype
where pb_visit.vetid = pb_vet.vetid
and pb_visit.animalid=pb_animal.animalid
and pb_client.clientid=pb_animal.clientid
and pb_animal.animaltypeid=pb_animaltype.animaltypeid
and pb_visit.status = 'Paid';

Comment: since there will be multiple value for each VETID, so when I try to putline inside that fetch into curosr loop, it will be something like
VETID  1......
  VISIT INFO 123
VETID  1......
  VISIT INFO 456
VETID  2......
  VISIT INFO 8910

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to use values fetched from first cursor in other query inside the loop.

In that case, if result will be no more than one row for each vetId use simple query right after `dbms_output` line:

```
select <columns> into <variables> from <2nd table> where id=vetRow.vetId;
```

If you expect more rows - use cursor with parameter and loop through it (but **loop inside loop is really bad idea** - better select from joined/left joined tables from first and second query).

---

EDIT: Case with parametrized cursor:

- added vetID as parameter to visitCursor
- changet loops into `FOR` version (if you like `OPEN ... FETCH ... INTO ... CLOSE` convention feel free to change it, IMO this change improved readability in this loop-inside-loop example)
- removed rest of code not relevant to my example

So you can try:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PAID_REPORT (PAYMENT_STATUS IN VARCHAR2) AS

cursor vetCursor is 
select pb_vet.vetid,visitid,lastname,firstname
from pb_visit,pb_vet
where pb_visit.vetid = pb_vet.vetid
and pb_visit.status = PAYMENT_STATUS
order by lastname, firstname;
vetRow vetCursor%rowtype;

cursor visitCursor (p_vetID pb_visit.vetid%TYPE) is
select visitid,name,lastname,firstname
from pb_client,pb_animal,pb_visit
where pb_client.cliEntid=pb_animal.clientid
and pb_visit.animalid=pb_animal.animalid
and status = PAYMENT_STATUS
and pb_visit.vetid = p_vetID;
visitRow visitCursor%rowtype;

BEGIN

for vetRow in vetCursor loop
  dbms_output.put_line('Veterinarian ID: '||vetRow.vetid||'   '||vetRow.lastname||','||vetRow.firstname);
  -- other vet-related code here
  for visitRow in visitCursor(vetRow.vetid) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Visit info:'||visitRow.visitid||'   '||visitRow.lastname||','||visitRow.firstname);
    -- other visit-related code here
  end loop;
end loop;

END PAID_REPORT;
```

Comment: IF I use singly query, since there will be multiple value for each VETID, so when I try to putline inside that fetch into curosr loop, it will be something like                                           

'VETID  1......
  VISIT INFO 123
VETID  1......
  VISIT INFO 456
VETID  2......
  VISIT INFO 8910
but what I want is something like
VETID  1......
  VISIT INFO 123
  VISIT INFO 456
VETID  2......
  VISIT INFO 8910'

Comment: ###,how can I write multi line comment?

Comment: To Chorel: thank you very much. it will return multiple value for each VETID. you said "use cursor with parameter and loop through it" the parameter you meant in my case would be VETID? then select ...from ...where id= VETID???the thing is I dont know what is this VETID.

Comment: @user2444017 - multiline comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`.  Share and enjoy.